# Laravel Validation not returning error

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, mass-assignment

I am new in Laravel.

This is my laravel controller:

```
public function store()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), City::$rules);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        }
        $image_temp=Input::file('image');
        $name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $data['image']='';
        if(Image::make($image_temp->getRealPath())->save('public/up/city/'.$name)){
            $data['image']='up/city/'.$name;
        }
        City::create($data);
        return Redirect::route('admin.cities.index');
    }
```

and This is my model:

```
class City extends \Eloquent {
   protected $primaryKey='city_id';

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
         'title'     => 'required',
         'image'     => 'mimes:jpeg',
         'parent_id' => 'required',
         'name'      => 'required',
         'english_name'=>'unique:cities,english_name|required'

    ];
    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'parent_id', 'english_name','population','phone_prefix','image'];
}
```

And I have a form I use `{{ $errors->first('inputName','<p class="error">:message</p>') }}` bellow my form inputs, when I send form without filling inputs I get error under each form input. But when I fill out all form inputs and then submit the Laarvel validation return fail (I mean mass assignment not working and not registering, and redirects back to create page.) **what is the problem?**

Comment: Looks to me like you forgot `title` in the `$fillable` array.

Comment: `City::$rules` looks wonky to me... Should it be `City::rules` or `City->rules`?

Comment: @TimLewis It is the right syntax for accessing static properties.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Oh static, right. It's still ugly :P

Comment: @TimLewis Yep I don't like the syntax either...

Comment: @TimLewis what is ugly? my syntax? I am new in Laravel

Comment: @Asker Haha no, your syntax better than a lot I see on SO. The syntax on accessing static variables, as per my first comment.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Real big thanks, I really say thanks to you becouse of your grate answers.. THANKS, May I have you own website address or your E-mail. Thanks

Comment: @TimLewis. Thanks for your comments and for your help ♥

Comment: @Asker No problem, keep up the good work!

Comment: @Asker Haha yes your syntax totally fine... You're welcome, I added an answer so you have something to accept ;) Generally no, I don't like giving out my personal contact data. Why are you asking?

Comment: @Asker I'm currently rebuilding my site, if it's finished I'll add it to my StackOverflow profile and let you know (if you're still active then)

Comment: @Asker I wouldn't do that. Not that I wouldn't like it but there are "serial voting" detection algorithms that will detect these votes and reverse them...

Comment: @lukasgeiter of course I know that. Stackoverflow is so smart and my real account is temporary blocked for spamming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost always the reason for a **mass assignment error** is a missing attribute in the `$fillable` array. In your case it is `title`.

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'name', 'parent_id', 'english_name','population','phone_prefix','image'];
                          ^
```

#### Edit

Apparently the problem was actually that the `title` in the `$rules` array, which should have been `name`...

Comment: Oh you are wrong here, the problem is from my **$rules** here. I mean the `title` in `$rules` array should be `name`. And anyway your answer is true because both of them should be same.Thanks

Comment: Accepted + up vote + A big thanks + Give me your Email :) (Kidding)

Comment: can you please answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985327/laravel-controller-update-method-not-working